# Default Starting Cell in new worksheet

Tags: excel

I have been unable to find a solution for this problem: When adding a new worksheet in an Excel workbook, the active cell moves to D20.  This behavior is consistent across ALL workbooks that I open or use (new or opening existing workbooks).  There are no macros on "ThisWorkbook" or any of the sheets.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you (or someone else) maybe create a custom sheet template?

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win016.htm

I saved a single-sheet workbook (with D20 selected) as "sheet.xlt" in my XLSTART folder, and each time I add a new sheet in a workbook I get that same selection in the new sheet.

Comment: THIS IS CORRECT!  Only change, had to navigate to C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART and change Sheet.xltx